# Python to Pyspark Functions UDF how to output a list of lists

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a function in python (many different functions but same case) and I'm converting it to PySpark, however, this function has as input one list of different integer types and has one output which is a list, which consists of n number of lists inside of it of Integer type, one example:

```
#I know some libraries are not necessary righ now
import pyspark
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, FloatType, StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

my_function_input([4,5,7,8,10, 11]) 
my_function_output[[4, 5], [7, 8], [10, 11]]
```

this is what I'm trying but gives an error when trying to use it

```
pyspark_my_function = udf(my_function, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [4, 5, 6, 8, 9] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

I have some other functions which have 2 or 3 outputs which are also lists of lists inside of each. How could I transform them? I have tried this

```
schema = StructType([StructField("output1", ArrayType(IntegerType()), nullable=False), 
                     StructField("output2", ArrayType(IntegerType()), nullable=False)])

pyspark_function = udf(my_function, schema)
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have problems with both input and output of the UDF. Take a look at the sample code below.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = (spark
    .sparkContext
    .parallelize([
        ([4,5,7,8,9],),
    ])
    .toDF(['A'])
 )

def myfunc(a):
    return [[4, 5], [7, 8], [10, 11]]

(df
    .withColumn('test', F.udf(myfunc, T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType())))('A'))
    .show()
)

# Output
# +---------------+--------------------+
# |              A|                test|
# +---------------+--------------------+
# |[4, 5, 7, 8, 9]|[[4, 5], [7, 8], ...|
# +---------------+--------------------+
```